# Assign a value to a PHP variable depending on which form button pressed

Tags: php, forms, variables

Well, it's the first time I'm using stackoverflow, so I'd looking foward to be clear.

How can I set a value for a PHP variable from a button press?

For example, if the user pressed  form button 1, $variable = 'false'; if it presses form button 2, $variable = 'true'... is that possible?

Thx, in advance

Comment: did it, didn't found what I want to know....that's why I asked

Comment: Just trying to be constructive.  Usually people will down-vote things you should find easily with a search.  Think your "first time" comment saved you some down-votes :)  Really just an FYI.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, set different values to same name submit buttons
like:

```
<input name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Choice1">
<input name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Choice2">
```

Then depending on which button is pressed in php $_POST['submitBtn'] will have value Choice1 or Choice2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.
You can put 2 (or more) submit buttons with the same name and different values into a form and then chack the value of the submit button via php:

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="somefile.php">
<input type="submit" name="sb" value="button1" />
<input type="submit" name="sb" value="button2" />
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$submitbutton = $_POST['sb'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML side just create two submit button:

```
<input name="click" type="submit" value="clickOne">
<input name="click" type="submit" value="clickTwo">
```

Then on the PHP side (assuming you are submitting with POST method):

```
switch ($_POST['click']) {
    case 'clickedOne':
        // first pressed
    break;
    case 'clickedTwo':
        // second pressed
    break;
    default:
        // something wrong
    break;
}
```