# In PHP how do you send data through a form without any data inputs apart from buttons?

Tags: php

Trying to find out which button the user has pressed. I want to get the value that is in the form-label when the corresponding button is pressed. Is this possible? Thanks

index.php

```
<html>

<form action="./process.php" method="post">

<?php 

for ($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<label>$index</label>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
    echo "<br>";
}

?>

</form>

</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php 

# I want to print the number here? So if the button next to number 1 was pressed it would be 1 printed here.

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not add that value as a hidden field? After all, this is not a PHP problem

Comment: In HTML you can use `echo '<input type="hidden" name="index' . $index . '" value="' . $index . '">';`.

Comment: If they use a hidden input, wouldn't *all* of them be posted to the server regardless of which button they press...?

Comment: That does work, however it does not allow me to figure out which exact button was pressed it just echo's 10 as that is the last number to be added to the $_POST["number"] value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign a value to a PHP variable depending on which form button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419405/assign-a-value-to-a-php-variable-depending-on-which-form-button-pressed)

Comment: OK, I'm not clearly not awake yet. You can give a name to the submit button, or move the form definition inside the loop, so you actually get 10 forms, instead of one, and you can use hidden input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the stumbling block here is the use of `<input type="submit">` in which the examples you've seen so far use `value="Submit"` to set the *text* of the button.

But if you use a `<button type="submit">` instead, you can set the text within the element and control its value separately:

```
for ($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<label>$index</label>";
    echo "<button type=\"submit\" name=\"myButton\" value=\"$index\">Submit</button>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Whichever button is clicked would be the only one posting its value to the server, and would be observable in `$_POST['myButton']`.

(As an aside... `type="submit"` is the default and doesn't *necessarily* need to be specified explicitly, but I personally consider it good practice to be explicit in these cases because we've often seen bugs/confusion when no type is specified and a form submit is *not* the intended action, but rather some client-side handler is.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom name to each submit buttons.

```
<?php 

for ($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<label>$index</label>";
    echo "<input name=\"submit_".$index."\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

And you can check which button has been submitted (and get their value):

```
for ($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit_'.$index])) {
        //$_POST['submit_'.$index] is your submitted button
    }
}
```